# Django RelatedObjectDoesNotExist After Upgrade to 2.2

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-related-manager

I've recently upgraded one of my Django projects from `1.9.6` to `2.2` and in doing so I'm getting a strange error around a specific `ForeignKey` relation.

#### models.py

```
class MyObject1(models.Model):
    myobject2 = models.ForeignKey(MyObject2, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

#### views.py

```
def my_view(request, id):
    try:
        my_object = MyObject1.objects.get(id = id)
    except:
        # do some stuff
    else:
        print (my_object.myobject2)
```

#### result

`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`

`MyObject1 has no myobject2`

at line `print (my_object.myobject2)`

I have confirmed via the Django shell that the instance in question does have a valid `myobject2` and I don't get that error when performing the same actions in the shell.

All other `ForeignKey` relations in the application work as expected except for this one.

This is quite puzzling and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does `print (my_object.myobject2_id)` output?

Comment: @Alasdair It throws the error I mentioned. I would just expect it to print a `None` value but that's not the case.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. I don't think your example code is enough to explain what's going on.

Comment: As an aside, Django 1.9 to Django 2.2 is a big leap. It might be better to upgrade to Django 1.11 LTS, fix any deprecation warnings, then upgrade to Django 2.2. That way you'll get to see deprecation warnings that you might otherwise miss, and you'll narrow down when the changes in Django occurred that are affecting your app.

Comment: Have you tried running showmigrations to see if some unexpected error shows up?